# GWT Error only when compiling for Internet Explorer 'com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBasedWidgetImpl' cannot be abstract

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-10

I can compile my gwt project fine for firefox and chrome, but as soon as I try and compile it for IE10+, I start getting these errors:

```
[ERROR] Line 46: Rebind result 'com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBasedWidgetImpl' cannot be abstract
```

I am using GWT 2.6

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you upgrade do GWT 2.7?

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the reply. I upgraded to 2.7 and I still get the same thing unfortunately.